# How does stacking and resolving work exactly?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

I understand that every card that is put onto the stack is resolved in the opposite order that it is put on (meaning the first card to be put onto a stack is the last one to be resolved), but here is my question.

Say I cast a [Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt). That goes onto the stack. My opponent passes priority back to me. Then, I cast [Twincast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Twincast), and that also goes onto the stack. Would Twincast copy Lightning Bolt, effectively doing an additional 3 damage to my opponent?

Or, would Lightning Bolt Resolve, do 3 damage, then Twincast would resolve and do nothing?

Comment: The whole point of Twincast is that it copies a spell on the stack.  They wouldn't have printed it if it does nothing

Answer (score 5):

Twincast copies Lightning Bolt, dealing 3 damage to whatever target you choose, then the original Lightning Bolt resolves as usual - a total of 6 damage. The first sentence of your question pretty much explains why. To be specific (and correct the detail about priority):

- You cast Lightning Bolt, putting it onto the stack.
- You gain priority before your opponent does. (Note that by default, it's assumed that you pass it - if you want to hang onto it, you should say so explicitly.)
- You cast Twincast, targeting Lightning Bolt. (The stack now has Lightning Bolt and Twincast on it.)
- You and your opponent both pass priority.
- Twincast resolves. It creates a copy of Lightning Bolt, optionally with a new target, and puts it on the stack. (The stack now has the original Lightning Bolt and the copy on it. Just one copy - not sure why you asked if it'd copy it twice.)
- You and your opponent both pass priority.
- The copy resolves, dealing 3 damage to whatever target you chose.
- You and your opponent both pass priority.
- The original resolves, dealing 3 damage.

For the record, the relevant rules about who gets priority when:

> 116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.
>
> 116.3c If a player has priority when he or she casts a spell, activates an ability, or takes a special action, that player receives priority afterward.

This is slightly important in this case because it means that you have to cast Twincast *before* you see if your opponent wants to respond to Lightning Bolt; if you pass priority to them before casting Twincast and they do nothing, then you've both passed and Lightning Bolt will resolve.

Comment: Worth mentioning that in tournaments (and often in casual play), priority is passed by default unless you state that you want to keep it.